# Configuration root node isn't found

Tags: symfony, configuration

I'm struggling with this problem already a couple of hours.
In one of my bundles I like to create a configuration so it's possible to configure the bundle in the app/config/config.yml file. This is the code:

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('jstree');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('default_tree')
                ->defaultValue('default')
                ->end()
            ->arrayNode('trees')
                ->isRequired()
                ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
                ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
                ->prototype('array')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('tree_class')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('tree_node_class')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end();

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

The bundles is named "HotfloSystemJsTreeBundle"

In my app/config/config.yml I have:

```
jstree:
    default_tree: default
    trees:
        default:
            tree_class: Hotflo\System\CoreBundle\Entity\PoliTree
            tree_node_class: Hotflo\System\CoreBundle\Entity\PoliTreeNode
```

I get the error:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "jstree"
```

I just can't find the error in my code. Someone can help?

Comment: Try  with `->root('hotflo_system_jstree')`

Comment: It isn't possible to use jstree instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the extension alias, if you want the root node name to be different

```
class HotfloSystemJsTreeExtension extends Extension
{
    //....

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'jstree';
    }
}
```